# Laravel validator allow only one field instead of both

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm getting two items in request but if both item are present I want to throw an error. like I have two fields base_model and base_model_id and If both fields are present it should throw an error that only one of this field is required. for now I am doing this but it's not validating properly.

```
public function store(Request $request){
         $request->validate([
                            'base_model' => 'required_without:base_model_file_id',
                            'base_model_file_id'=>'required_without:base_model',
                          ]);
                     }
```

Comment: So is it `base_model_id` like in your question or `base_model_file_id` like in your validation?! "_but it's not validating properly_" means what?

Comment: @brombeer it means if I'm sending both parameter it should say only one field is allowed at a time.

Comment: have you checked the `exclude_if` rule ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exclude-if

Comment: @ml59 it's for a specific value if present I guess but I'm checking on the existence of the key.